# How can I send messages from my BLE microcontroller to an RF module via UART?

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, uart, geckosdk

I have a BLE enabled microcontroller(Blue gecko bgm13p22). It takes in commands from a client(laptop). 
Now I have connected my microcontroller to an RF module via UART(rx,tx,vcc,gnd). How can I transfer my received messages which cam from bluetooth over to RF module via UART.

Thanks

Comment: That's a loaded question... Sounds like you need a tutorial.

Comment: *"How can I transfer my received messages..."* -- That's dictated by whatever message protocol your mystery *"RF module"* requires.